# Unit test for a React click-counting component

Tags: unit-testing, react.js, dom, jsx, state

Take this basic component using state:

```
export const InputChild = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const updateCount = () => setCount((prev) => prev + 1);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Count: </h1>
      <h2>{count}</h2>
      <button onClick={updateCount}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

And this test that just ensures the count increases after clicking the button:

```
  it('should increment', () => {
    act(() => {
      render(<InputChild />);
    });

    let h2 = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 2 });
    let count = Number(h2.innerHTML);
    const button = screen.getByText('Click');

    expect(count).toBe(0);
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();

    // fireEvent.click(button); // also works
    act(() => {
      button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
    });

    // count = Number(h2.innerHTML); // then use count below
    expect(Number(h2.innerHTML)).toBe(1);
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(Number(h2.innerHTML)).toBe(2);
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(Number(h2.innerHTML)).toBe(3);
  });
```

It’s annoying that I have to use `Number(h2.innerHTML)` in here in order to get the latest count value. Alternatively I could redefine count whenever clicking the button to get the latest innerHTML value (as the state changes):

```
count = Number(h2.innerHTML); 
expect(count).toBe(1);
fireEvent.click(button);
count = Number(h2.innerHTML);
expect(count).toBe(2);
fireEvent.click(button);
count = Number(h2.innerHTML);
expect(count).toBe(3);
```

But this seems too verbose.

Is there not a better way of doing this other than something like `Number(h2.innerHTML)`? I am new to unit testing and am trying to not write bad code, and the above just doesn’t feel right to me and I assume someone will have a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use `const` instead of `let`

```s
let h2 = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 2 });
```

Good that you're using [`screen`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-screen) and [`ByRole`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-byrole-most-of-the-time), but use `const` unless you plan to reassign the variable (and don't plan to reassign variables if you can possibly help it).

You could try `getByRole` for `const button = screen.getByText('Click');` too. If you change the text here or introduce another element that has the text `Click`, that can cause the test to fail when it shouldn't.

---

#### Use `fireEvent` rather than native DOM events

```js
// fireEvent.click(button); // also works
act(() => {
  button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
});
```

I'd prefer using `fireEvent` unless you have a specific reason not to. It's [already wrapped in `act`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#wrapping-things-in-act-unnecessarily) so you don't need to worry about that. Same goes for `render`, which should probably be broken out into a `beforeEach` block.

---

#### Use `.toHaveTextContent()` rather than `.innerHTML`

Instead of `h2.innerHTML`, you can use `expect(h2).toHaveTextContent()` brought to you by [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/). See [Common mistakes with React Testing Library: Using the wrong assertion](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-the-wrong-assertion).

In general, the philosophy of RTL is not to be dipping into native DOM elements unless you have to.

I'd write `expect(Number(h2.innerHTML)).toBe(1)` as `expect(h2.innerHTML).toBe("1")`. If the assertion fails, you'll get a much clearer error that compares `.innerHTML` against the string, rather than whatever weird value `Number()` might have returned, like `NaN`. (but using `toHaveTextContent()` as described above avoids the problem altogether)

---

#### Minor points

`expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();` is OK, but keep in mind that `getBy` will throw if it fails, so it's basically an always-pass. Kent [recommends keeping the explicit assertion anyway](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-get-variants-as-assertions) but I figured I'd point it out.

I'd probably keep the assertion right after the variable assignment rather than interleaving them. For example,

```js
let count = Number(h2.innerHTML);
const button = screen.getByText('Click');

expect(count).toBe(0);
expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
```

would be:

```js
const count = Number(h2.innerHTML);
expect(count).toBe(0);

const button = screen.getByText('Click');
expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
```

or with jest-dom and other suggestions:

```js
expect(h2).toHaveTextContent("0");

const button = screen.getByRole('Button');
expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: great advice, thank you very much for your help! quick question: do you know what is best to use for button clicks? e.g. dispatchEvent vs fireEvent (as you pointed out) vs userEvent? It seems like there are many ways to skin a cat but the best way is unclear

Comment: Good question. Going back to Kent's article I linked throughout, there's a section: [Not using `@testing-library/user-event`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-testing-libraryuser-event) which mimics the user's actions better. TBH, I've just used `fireEvent` which has been sufficient for my unit testing needs. I've relied on E2E tests with Puppeteer/Cypress to provide that "real user" simulation with trusted events, but Kent's the expert, and it seems good to apply that philosophy to unit tests too.

Comment: that's interesting to know. A course I also undertook also suggested just using userEvent over fireEvent, although it seems that they're both similar and that both would probably work. You can only get so far with unit tests and I am yet to explore e2e tests, and as you say, they will probably provide a better simulation for those cases